# How to make my first-child in css work properly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

I wanted to remove the red background in the last article-container. Anyway here are the html code I'm trying to work on...

```
<section id="intro" class="intro text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                    text 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                    text 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                    text 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                    text 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and my css I'm trying to do is this

```
div.article-container {
    background-color: red;
}

div.article-container:last-child {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Is there any css code for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make a fiddle with a working example

Comment: Hi @RobbinvanderJagt just check out the answer below that help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use last child selector on `.row` and set the `background-color: white;` to it's child `.article-container`. Check below is an example.

```css
div.article-container {
  background-color: red;
}
.row:last-child .article-container {
  /* Change color as desired */
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="intro" class="intro text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi @Pugazh thanks for answering my question first with explanation! And thanks to other answers too that I gave up though :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, I think it's help you

```
.row:last-child .article-container {
            background-color: white;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that, in the posted HTML, the `div.article-container` element is the only child of its parent, and is therefore the `:last-child` (as well as `:first-child`) of its parent the selector you supply will always match; instead you need the `div.article-container` child of the last `.row` element:

```
div.row:last-child div.article-container {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```css
div.article-container {
  background-color: red;
}
div.row:last-child div.article-container {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="intro text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
          text 4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/2d7zj135/1/)**

css code :

```
.row:last-child  div.article-container{
background-color: white;
}
```

use `row:last-child` instead of `div.article-container:last-child`
`div.article-container:last-child` will select all the div with that class because there is only 1 `div.article-container` in each row

the `:first-child` `:last-child` `:nth-child` selectors only work if the elements with same classes/ids are nested in a parent element...and they are the only ones there.

**for eg this will work.**

```
<parent>
  <elem>
  <elem>
  <elem>
  <elem>
</parent>
```

**this won't work :**

```
<parent>
  <elem>
  <elem>
  <elem>
  <elem>
  <other element>
</parent>
```

**this will work but not as you wanted**

```
<parent>
  <elem>
</parent>
<parent>
  <elem>
</parent>
<parent>
  <elem>
</parent>
<parent>
  <elem>
</parent>
```

`elem:first-child` will select the first child in the same parent; so in this case ( as in yours ) `elem:first-child` will return all the elements and is the same as `elem:last-child` or `elem:nth-child(n)`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/064rwxLx/) for you to show you a working example.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="intro" class="intro text-center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                text 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                text 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                text 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wp1 animated fadeInLeft">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 article-container">
                text 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.article-container {
    background-color: red;
}

div.row:last-child .article-container {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector would be

```
.section .row:last-child .article-container
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/yJbjQy

```
.article-container { background-color: red; }
#intro .row:last-child .article-container { background-color: transparent; }
```

Answer (score 0):

it won't work that way.

```
.intro .row:last-child .article-container {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

because you can only target the immediate child for nth styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    background-color: red;
}

.row:last-child {
    background-color: white;
}
```